# python logistic regression: return actual value, not 1 or 0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm running a logistic regression model in Python using sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.

I know how to return the predictions that the model makes (either 0 or 1), but I would like to return the ACTUAL number, the decimal between 0 and 1, that the model produces before it rounds.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba).

An example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

model = LogisticRegression()

X = [[0, 1, 0], [2, 2, 1], [3, 1, 0]]

y = [0, 1, 1]

model.fit(X, y)
Out[8]: 
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False)

model.predict_proba(X)
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.53591311,  0.46408689],
       [ 0.182901  ,  0.817099  ],
       [ 0.11778519,  0.88221481]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that it's that simple--I've never used that before.